# Get members quantity in Agora Voice call sdk

Tags: agora.io

I tried to find a method to get the members that are joined in the channel but I wasn't able to find a solution. What I'm trying to do is to change the ui if the other person is already in the call or if you should wait to start talking.
The only method I was able to use is the

> onUserJoin(uid: Int, elapsed: Int)

The problem is that if both users join the channel at the same time, it won't be triggered

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried onRemoteVideoStateChanged call back? https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1_i_rtc_channel_event_handler.html?platform=Android#a6ac9d139c17c849e14cc86dff5846e3b

Either of those should do the work. If you still have this issue, please file a ticket to Agora support: https://agora-ticket.agora.io/form/69/issue/42748592a2f6460b9e89c452184e0c34

Comment: I'm not using the video call sdk, it's just a voice call. I'm sorry but I don't get why should I use that callback

Comment: Sorry i was trying to say onRemoteAudioStateChanged callback. Here is the API reference. 
https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1_i_rtc_channel_event_handler.html?platform=Android#a8243351d18932b1678533bee01a856ca